# JQuery add/remove class not working the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form to register user with some info. Upon submit, an ajax call is made which inserts the data into the DB, and returns a status code. Depending upon the status, I show a div. The div has an initial class "hidden", and a close button. Upon return from the php, I remove the "hidden" class and add the "alert-danger" or "alert-success" class.

Once the user clicks the close(x) button, I add the "hidden" class again, and check if the element has "alert-danger" or "alert-success" class and remove that as well. This works (or at least it hides) for the first time. However, the div doesn't show up the second time.

What is it that I am missing here?

Here's the div

```
<div class="alert alert-block fade in status hidden">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
 <h4 class="message-head"></h4>   
 <p class="message"></p>   
</div>
```

Here's the code run upon success/error

```
$.ajax({
  type:"post",
  url:"register.php",
  data:"name="+name+"&phone="+phone+"&email="+email+"&msg="+msg,
  success:function(data){

  if(data.status === 'success'){
     //show the status msg
     $('.message-head').text("Thank You");
     $('.message').text("Your Request has been taken");
     $(".status").removeClass("hidden").addClass('alert-success');

      }else {
     $('.message-head').text("Sorry");
     $('.message').text("There is some Error. Please Try Again Later");
     //alert(data.status);
     $('.status').removeClass('hidden').addClass('alert-danger');
}}
```

And here's the code for the close button click

```
$('.close').click(function(){
 if ( $('.status').hasClass("alert-danger") ) {
 $('.status').removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("hidden");
}else if ( $('.status').hasClass("alert-success") ) {
 $('.status').removeClass("alert-success").addClass("hidden");
}
});
```

Comment: add a breakpoint (debugger) to your close click. Check what's in the $(".status") selector when you do it for the second time.

Comment: Are you using a bootstrap alert? Closing the alert **removes the element from the dom**. So that's probably what's happening here. Perhaps try using the bootstrap `$().alert()` functions instead.

Comment: Mathieu - I checked in the Developer tool. What happens is when I click on "close" button, the entire div vanishes. And hence, there's no way to load it the second time.

Comment: Christian - You're probably correct. The "status" div is removed from the dom the first time I click on close. But it also gets removed when I use $('.status').alert(), with no custom code for close. Besides if I use only alert(), I wouldn't be able to give a green/red alert background from bootstrap, which otherwise is possible using alert-danger/alert-success

Answer (score 1):

I put together a simple fiddle for you

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/qyyegwhu/1/

Are you including the class .hidden in css:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

I'm having trouble replicating the issue otherwise?

Comment: It's strange that it's working perfectly fine in your example but not when I use your code in a new file. What happens is that the first time the alert would come. But when I click on "close", the entire div vanishes. I have tried hidden class from bootstrap but I have also tried to do it in the css.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I believe that closing Bootstrap alerts should work out of the box when you open them with the bootstrap JS Function.

This should work for opening:

```
$('.message-head').text("Thank You");
$('.message').text("Your Request has been taken");
$('.alert').alert();
```

The code for closing the alert is not needed, because the alert is closed automatically like in the bootstrap example http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts

EDIT: Another approach would be to create the alert with javascript. This would be the solution for both of your problems. (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nfbbzuo/4/) )

Comment: Thank you. This would open the alert, and the closing would be automatic like you said. But there are 2 problems here:              1. The alert-danger or alert-success can't be applied. and 2. Once we close, the element will be removed from dom, and not appear again, if the user re-submits the form